# Regex for last point or comma in string

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I'm looking for a regex with gives me the last occurance of a point or a comma in a string (whichever one is the further back)

From what I googled myself I got this one `([,\.])(?!.*\1)` but this gives me two results per string which isnt what I wanted.

I hope somebody can help me as I'm struggeling for the correct keyword to google for.

Cheers and thank you very much in advance

Comment: It should be like this `[,.](?=[^,.\r\n]*$)` https://regex101.com/r/GCCg5e/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This pattern `([,\.])(?!.*\1)` matches the last comma or dot asserting not any of the 2 being present on the right anymore.

That can occur for both a dot and a comma so you could possibly [get 2 matches](https://regex101.com/r/E2ATLq/1).

If you want a single match, you can match one of them and assert no more occurrences of either one of them to the right using a negated character class `[^,.\r\n]*` matching any char except the listed characters.

Note that you don't need the capture group for a match only.

```
[,.](?=[^,.\r\n]*$)
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GCCg5e/1).

Answer (score 0):

In this regex pattern the first capturing group is the last comma or point in each line.
We achieve this by looking for a comma or point and not allowing a point, comma or line ending between it and the end of the line.

```
([.,])[^.,\n\r]*$
```

Comment: @Cary Swoveland : Thank you - I've modified and used `\r\n`and it's working as I intended. Regards